# Постановка двоеточия при объяснении причины

Tags: пунктуация

Я выписал вопрос: мне надо его задать на форуме.

В данном случае указание на причину и назначение может предваряться двоеточием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Всё верно.
*Я выписал вопрос: мне надо его задать на форуме.*